# Can I wrap text in a <span> around a circle-shaped element?

Tags: html, css

I need to use a block of HTML in a webview in an iPhone app. It needs to be dynamically layered out so that localized text will give the same layout.

To illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, I have this:

```
___________________________
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|  text here              |
|  and here               |
|                         |
|  but there is a         |
|  circle right           |
|  here that              |
|  can't                  |
|  have                   |
|  text                   |
___________________________
```

Imagine a circle in the lower right, I'm terrible with ASCII art. Basically, the app supports several languages, some more verbatim then others.

Is there a way to create some sort of mask so that the text wraps around the circle-shape in the bottom right, regardless of how much text there is?

Answer (score 1):

Even though your element is displaying as a circle it will still basically be a block (box) shaped element. This means that you can't wrap the text around the curve.

You could cheat by positioning spans with individual bits of text but that would be a nightmare.

Here's a really nasty way to achieve what you want:

http://www.webbedenvironments.com/dhtml_css_advanced/code/05_Layout/CurvedTextWrapping/index.html